# Angular Material Icon Button Changed from Version 14 to 15?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14, angular15

As I updated my app's Angular version from 14 to 15 - including all packages like material design - the mat-icon-button now has a circular background which it hadn't before. And which it doesn't have to have according to the documentation:

[image: Angular Material 15]

[image: Angular Material 14]

The blue background is the normal background of my page.

The code is very straight forward and doesn't change from Angular 14 to 15:

```
<button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: See https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Comment: Perfect help :-) Will you post this answer or should I?

Comment: I think a post specific to your case may be helpful to future users, please post a self answer if you have one

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew mentioned there is a migration guide for material:

https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Running the migration tools solved the problem:

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

The migration tool changed e.g. the import for all material components to something like:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Previous syntax (version 14 and below) -->
<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>

<!-- New syntax (version 15 and above) -->
<mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</mat-icon-button>
```